# Unintentional popup FORM closing when clicking on a BUTTON or on a INPUT ( with JS code)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, popup

I'm finding a strange behaviour in a popup FORM when I click on a BUTTON (that operates on some object using a JS code), and on a INPUT (used for submit): in both cases, the form closes, and it is an unexpected action.
Probably is due to something very easy and common that I'm not fixing, but i can't find it.

This is the HTML interested part:

```
        <form name="contactform" id="contactform" class="contact-form">
          <div class="contactform-container">
            <a href="" class="closeButton"></a>
            <div class="common">
              <label for="name">Nome</label>
              <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
            </div>
            <div class="common">
              <label for="name">Cognome</label>
              <input type="text" id="familyName" name="familyName" />
            </div>
            <div class="common">
              <label for="email">e-mail</label>
              <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
            </div>
            <div class="message">
              <label for="message">Annotazioni</label>
              <textarea name="message" id="message" class="message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="passRow">
              <fieldset class="validatePass">
                <div class="formGroup">
                  <label class="formLabel"for="password">Password
                    <span class="passErr"></span>
                  </label>
                  <div class="passWrapper">
                    <input type="password"
                    id="password"
                    class="form-control input-md"
                    name="password"
                    placeholder="Enter your password">
                    <span class="showPass">
                      <i class="fas fa-eye-slash"></i>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <p class="progress">Livello di sicurezza</p>
                  <div id="progressBar">
                    <div></div>
                  </div>
                  <ul id="progressList">
                    <li>Un carattere minuscolo e uno maiuscolo</li>
                    <li>Un numero</li>
                    <li>Un carattere speciale tra "!,%,&amp;,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,-"</li>
                    <li>Lunghezza minima: 8 caratteri</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="securityCaptcha">
              <p>Inserire il codice nei riquadri sottostanti</p>
              <div class="first row">
                <div class="refCheck">
                  <canvas class="valiCaptcha"></canvas>
                </div>
                <div class="refCheck">
                  <canvas class="valiCaptcha"></canvas>
                </div>
                <div class="refCheck">
                  <canvas class="valiCaptcha"></canvas>
                </div>
                <div class="refCheck last">
                  <canvas class="valiCaptcha"></canvas>
                  <button class="reloadButton">
                    <i class="fas fa-redo"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="second row">
                <div class="refCheck">
                  <input type="text" name="" maxlength="1">
                </div>
                <div class="refCheck">
                  <input type="text" name="" maxlength="1">
                </div>
                <div class="refCheck">
                  <input type="text" name="" maxlength="1">
                </div>
                <div class="refCheck">
                  <input type="text" name="" maxlength="1">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="contactArea">
              <p>Compilare tutti i dati per la prenotazione.</p>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="send">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

The BUTTON that create problem is the one with class **reloadButton**.

The INPUT is the one with id **submit**.

I think css aren't necessary.

Regarding the JS part:

```
let formEls = formPopup.querySelectorAll('.common, .message, .note');
let charCode = [];
const refreshButton = document.querySelectorAll('.reloadButton')[0];
const passInput = document.getElementById('password');

window.onload = function () {
  document.querySelector('#reserveBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
    formPopup.classList.add('active');
  });

  getCode();
  formPopup.querySelector('.closeButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
    cleanForm();
    formPopup.classList.remove('active');
  });

  formPopup.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
      if (ev.target.id == 'contactform-bg') {
        cleanForm();
        formPopup.classList.remove('active');
      }
    });
  refreshButton.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    charCode = [];
    getCode();
  });

  passInput.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    passVal = passInput.value;
    checkPass(passVal);
  });

};

let cleanForm = function () {
  formEls.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.classList.remove('typing');
  });
  // console.log(window['contactform-bg'].innerHTML);
  // console.log(document.getElementById('contactform').innerHTML);
  // console.log(document.contactform.innerHTML);
  document.contactform.name.value = '';
  document.contactform.familyName.value = '';
  document.contactform.email.value = '';
  document.contactform.message.value = '';
  passInput.value = '';
};

function getCode() {
  let sChars = 'A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,)';
  let arrayChars = sChars.split(',');
  for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    // trova un indice casuale tra 0 e la lunghezza dell'array
    RefIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayChars.length);

    // assegna il carattere estratto dall'array (strana indicazione del font come giapponese(??)
    let char = arrayChars[RefIndex];
    charCode[i] = char.toLowerCase;
    createImgCaptcha(char, i);
  }
}
```

I avoid to add the **createImgCaptcha** function because it just create CANVAS and doesn't have any impact on the matter.

Is there anyone able to explain to me why the FORM closes? I tried following the steps in JS but found no errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The primary purpose of a submit button is that when you click it, the form it is in will be submitted and the browser will navigate to the new page.

Comment: "Closing" happens, when the `active` class gets removed, I'd assume? Well there is only two places in your code where you do that, remove this class - so do a bit of debugging to figure out which of the two it is, and then check the details of the event that happened and triggered this.

Comment: Well, @Quentin, i tried adding `onclick="stopEvent(event);"` to the INPUT and this function in JS: `function stopEvent(event)
{
  event.stopPropagation();
}` but it still close. So, I assume that the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @CBroe I tried commenting both the functions but the FORM still close. Strange also that the close button (in HTML `<a href="" class="closeButton"></a>`) still acts, even if the addEventListener in JS is commented...

Comment: If your `.reloadButton` is not supposed to submit the form, but only to trigger some JS action - then you should add `type="button"` to it, otherwise it will be a submit button by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problems and fixed them.
There were little mistakes one different from another. So, I list them:

1. The "FORM close object": there was a missing '#' characer in the *ref* attribute, so I changed the HTML from `<a href="" class="closeButton"></a>` to `<a href="#" class="closeButton" type="text/html"></a>`, adding also the *type* attribute for greater completeness.
2. The "class reloadButton": I finally read that a `<button>Click to do something</button>` is a default submit button. I didn't know... so, I just added the right type attribute to solve, in this way: `<button class="reloadButton" type="button">`.
3. The "submit button": in this case, I changed the prevent JS command: `function stopEvent(event) { event.preventDefault();}`.

Now, everything works correctly. Sorry if I bored you with these silly things; either way, it's always best to learn from mistakes.